# IPythonで仮想環境を切り替える方法を教えてください

Tags: python, ipython

## 環境

- Python 3.6.5
- IPython 6.4.0
- conda 4.5.8
- Anaconda 3.5.2

## やりたいこと

IPythonで使う仮想環境を切り替えたいです。

私のPCの仮想環境は以下の通りです。

```
C:\Users\yuji3>conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\yuji3\Anaconda3_5.2.0
test                     C:\Users\yuji3\Anaconda3_5.2.0\envs\test
```

IPythonで`test`という仮想環境を使いたいです。

## 質問

IPythonで`test`という仮想環境を使には、どうすればよいですか？

Jupyter Notebookで仮想環境を切り替える方法は見つかりましたが、IPythonで切り替える方法は見つかりませんでした。
https://qiita.com/tomochiii/items/8b937f15c79a0c3eae0e

## 回答をいただいた上での補足

仮想環境を切り替えて、pandasのバージョンを確認したいです。

```
>activate base
>pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 0.23.3
>activate test
>pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 0.23.1
>activate test
```

以下のいずれの場合も、pandasのバージョンは`0.23.3`で、`0.23.1`ではありませんでした。

- 仮想環境`test`に切り替えてから、`ipython`コマンドを実行
- `jupyter console --kernel=test` を実行
- Jupyter Notebookから、kernelを選択

仮想環境`test`に切り替えてから、`python`コマンドを実行した際は、pandasのバージョンが`0.23.1`でした。

何が原因でしょうか？
カーネルは、以下のコマンドでインストールしました。

```
> ipython kernel install --user --name=test --display-name=test
>jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  test       C:\Users\yuji3\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\test
  python3    C:\Users\yuji3\Anaconda3_5.2.0\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

`jupyter console --kernel=test` でPython環境を確認したところ、`test`でなくデフォルト（`base`）の環境でした。

```
In [1]: sys.executable
Out[1]: 'C:\\Users\\yuji3\\Anaconda3_5.2.0\\python.exe'
```

Comment: 問題切り分けのためには、`ipython`上で、`import sys; sys.executable`で表示されるpythonの環境に望んでいる`pandas`のバージョンがインストールされているか確認すると良いようです。(https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2506)

Comment: `sys.executable`で確認したところ、デフォルトのPython環境でした。

Comment: カーネルとしてデフォルトのPython環境が指定されているのだと思います。デフォルトのPython環境で`pip show pandas`とするとipythonと同じバージョンが表示されるのではと思います。

Comment: おっしゃるとおり`pip show`と同じバージョンでした。なぜ、デフォルトのPython環境が指定されてしまっているのでしょうか？

Comment: 仮想環境にJupyterがインストールされていないためです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPythonの場合は、普通に`activate test`で仮想環境を切り替えて、`ipython`でその仮想環境のIPythonを起動させます。コマンド履歴も使えるので不便なことはないと思います。

なお、仮想環境に`IPython`がインストールできていない場合は`IPython`をインストールします。仮想環境に`IPython`がインストールできていない場合は、優先度は低いですがbase(root)へのパスが通っているのでbase(root)の`IPython`が起動します。

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Admin> activate
(root) PS C:\Users\Admin> ipython
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: exit
(root) PS C:\Users\Admin> activate test
(test) PS C:\Users\Admin> ipython
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

また、次のように`activate test`と`ipython`を続けて入力すれば、その環境のIPythonを直ぐに起動できます。なお、コマンドプロンプトを使う場合は、`activate test & ipython`となります。

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Admin> activate test; ipython
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```